# OData support in ASP.Net Web API RTM 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api, odata

How to implement the OData in ASP .Net Web API using Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Web API OData preview package - http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData

You can find overview articles by Alex James here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2012/08/15/odata-support-in-asp-net-web-api.aspx

There is **no full support for OData in Web API at the moment**. The best you can do for the time being is go with the preview package above.

It was released on the same day as Web API RTM was released, to provide simple support for OData and preview some functionalities (that's why it's called *alpha*). Full package is coming later this fall.

Comment: I want the OData support in ASP Net Web API MVC 4 RTM.

Comment: This package is purposely built for RTM... - will not work with earlier versions. Also the blogs post is RTM specific.